# Android - ImageView margins not appearing in LinearLayout

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, margins, layoutparams

Right now, I'm struggling to accomplish something as simple as adding margin space between my child ImageViews within a custom LinearLayout (modified RadioGroup that is designed to take in a custom ImageView that implements Checkable, didn't override onMesarue). Long story short, these images are of a fixed dimension (60x60dip), and since they are dynamic (from the web), I had to add them dynamically like so:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
            ImageViewRadioButton childImage = new ImageViewRadioButton(mContext);
            float imagehWidthHeight = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_width_and_height);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) imageWidthHeight, (int) imageWidthHeight);
            int imageSpacing = Utils.dipsToPixels(10, mContext);
            int innerPadding = Utils.dipsToPixels(5, mContext);

            imageParams.leftMargin = imageSpacing;
            imageParams.rightMargin = imageSpacing;
            childImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            childImage.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
            childImage.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_pressed));
            childImage.setPadding(innerPadding, innerPadding, innerPadding, innerPadding);
            childImage.setClickable(true);
            //other non-image properties...
            imageContainer.addView(childImage);
        }
```

The only thing that does work is the padding, which it spaces it out properly. However, I am not seeing any space between the padding of each child (margins). Am I doing this correctly, or is there a better way of doing it short of overriding onMeasure to factor in each child's margins?

Answer (score 0):

You had create `imageParams` but you are not using that parameters in your code instead of `imageParams` you are using   `swatchParams` parameter. And you had not put a code of `swatchParams` parameter.

Comment: Obviously, it's an example, so that was supposed to be imageParams. Even then when I created the LayoutParams object and passed it into the view, it still didn't work.